# extract item from list of dictionaries

Tags: python

Suppose you have a list of dictionaries like this one:

```
a = [ {'name':'pippo', 'age':'5'} , {'name':'pluto', 'age':'7'} ]
```

What do you to extract from this list only the dict where name==pluto?
To make things a little bit harder, consider that I cannot do any import

Comment: what do you want to extract? :/

Comment: the dictionary, i.e. {'name':'pluto', 'age':'7'}

Answer (score 41, accepted):

List comprehension is ideal for this:

```
[d for d in a if d['name'] == 'pluto']
```

Comment: It's 'if' not 'where'. Edit: I see you fixed it. It's worth mentioning that this is still a list, as there is a potential for multiple results with that value - if you are sure there is only one and only want one, just access the element in position 0 on that new list.

Comment: @Lattyware Yeah, I edited it as soon as I saw it. You were quick to notice :) And yes, it will produce a list. Using [0] directly is dangerous though if the result will be an empty list. You can use something like `x = x[0] if x else {}` on the result. Or if the `name` is unique then `[x] = [d for d in a if d['name'] == 'pluto'] or [{}]`

Comment: @rplnt Indeed, that's why I said 'if you are sure there is one, and only one' - if there are none, or more than one, you are going to end up with problems, albeit problems you have now given elegant solutions to. Thanks for clarifying.

Comment: Is there any special reason as to why there's a need of using  [.........] as the output parethesis

Comment: @PranjalGupta In what example? On the right side, it's a syntax for list comprehension (check documentation). On the lest side (`[x] = ...`) it means that we will extract items from collection on the right side.
Imagine that 
`n = [1]`
then
`[x] = n`
and that is equal to
`x = n[0]`
resulting in
`x = 1`

Answer (score 14):

Apart from list comprehension that other responses give it to you, you can also do it with a filter and a lambda:

```
filter(lambda x: x.get('name') == 'pluto',a)
```

Answer (score 4):

```
>>> [d['age'] for d in a if d['name']=='pluto']
['7']
```

Comment: Given they didn't specify, one would presume they want to extract the whole dict, but if they want something in particular, then this is a good solution.

Answer (score 3):

Use a list comprehension which picks out the correct dict in the list of dicts.

```
 >>> [d for d in a if d['name']=='pluto']
 [{'age': '7', 'name': 'pluto'}]
```

Or, if you're not sure if all of the dicts in `a` have a 'name' key,

```
 >>> [d for d in a if d.get('name')=='pluto']
 [{'age': '7', 'name': 'pluto'}]
```

Note that both of these return a *list*. If you know that there is only one matching entry, you can add `[0]` to the end to return the actual dict:

```
 >>> [d for d in a if d['name']=='pluto'][0]
 {'age': '7', 'name': 'pluto'}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
[d for d in a if d['name'] == 'pluto']
```